# CI/CD to multiple clients environments

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I have a Spring Boot application under gitlab. Today I'm using gitlab CI/CD and have some steps:

1. Build application (generate jar)
2. Test
3. Delivery in client (01) machine correct folder.
4. Start application using production profile, using Systemd in centos 8. This profile contains specific configs to client production.
   **Important**: Gitlab runner runs under client infrastructure because we can't access your infrastructure from the internet.

Now I got a new client (02) that should use same project code, but in totally different environment. Let's see some difficulties:

1. The gitlab runner runs under client 01 only
2. Client 02 don't accept access from internet to your infrastructure too, like client 01. So, I can use same Gitlab runner to both clients.
3. I should have a application.properties to each client, today I just have it separated by profiles inside code.
4. Client 02 use centos6, so I don't have Systemd to start service. I should use SysV. So, a different approach to start service.

I thought in one solution to this but I would like to know if exist something better, I really like the Gitlab ci/cd interface.

**My solution:** install Jenkins in each client infrastructure and make it listen Gitlab commits. Each Jenkins, in each client will take care about install and configure application.

To solve the problem with application.properties, I will create a repository just for it, separated with client name. So, I will have something like this: application-client01.properties and etc. Jenkins will just pull correct properties, because will be installed in client environment.

Some better solution ?

Comment: You can check out environments in GitLab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments.html 
It should be possible to set up different targets to push your changes to.
They also have file type environment variables:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#file-type
I don't know if `application.properties` would fit in one of those files though.

Comment: Sorry but with this documentation I don't get how environments can help me. Remember I have two delivery in two infrastructure, running different runners.

Comment: Can you use `tags:` in the GitLab jobs to separate between the two runners? You would have two deploy jobs where one has `tags: client_01` and the other has `tags: client_02`?

Comment: Ok, and when I will need use "Environments" ? I understand the tags strategy but I don't get the needed to use Envrionments.